# Unable to login again, once I log out using Angular Social Login

Tags: angular, google-signin, angular-social-login

Here is my button element:

```
<div class="dialog"><div class="btn btn-warning" *ngIf="!user" href="#" (click)="signInWithGoogle()">{{label}}<img src="{{img}}"/></div>
</div>
<div class="dialog" *ngIf="user"><div class="btn btn-warning"  href="#" (click)="signOut()">{{label}}<img src="{{img}}" alt="{{alt}}"/></div>
</div>
```

Here is button.ts

```
  public userDetails: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
    const storage = localStorage.getItem('google_auth');

    if (storage) {
      this.userDetails = JSON.parse(storage);
    } else {
      this.signOut();
    }
  }

  googleLoginOptions = {
    scope: 'profile email'
  };
 signInWithGoogle() {
  this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,this.googleLoginOptions).then((data) => {
    localStorage.setItem('google_auth', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/panel').then();
   });
 }

  signOut(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('google_auth');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/').then(this.refreshGoogleToken);
  }
 refreshGoogleToken(): void {
  this.authService.refreshAuthToken(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
}
```

Once the session is logged out, the sign up button does not get rendered and I have to refresh to log in.

Comment: Do login request sent in the second time?

Comment: Does your `user` object still exist upon signout? If so, your button wouldn't be rendered based on its condition, ie `*ngIf="!user"`.